# Hibernate does not classify entity as dirty if a JSON object is modified and therefore no updates are issued

Tags: database, hibernate, orm

The scenario:

Latest Hibernate, Latest Spring Boot.

DB table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_case (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  people json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class TestCase {
  @Id  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  public long id;
  
  @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
  public List<Person> people;
  
  public class Person {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
  }
}
```

Create an entity with a list of one or more Person objects in the people ArrayList.

Retrieve it by its ID, and edit the firstName on testCaseEntity.people.get(0).firstName.

Call merge on the entity. Note that changes to the list of People is NOT persisted to the database.

The only way I have been able to get this to update is by detaching the entity after retrieving it, but before calling merge.

Is there something I am missing here?